# Ajax not loading new page correctly

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a login form which I currently use AJAX to display the error messages from my `login.php` script, e.g. "incorrect email", onto a div in my login form on my `index.php` rather than loading a new page with the errors on them.

However when the details are correct and the login is successful, it also displays the entire successful page location onto that div inside my login form too. I don't know how to fix this, I have tried an if statement to say if it is successful load a new location, but still doesn't work. Here is my AJAX for my login form:

```js
$("#login_button").click(function() {
  $.post($("#login_form").attr("action"),
    $("#login_form :input").serializeArray(),
    function(info) {
      if (info.status != null) {
        header('Location: home.php');
      } else {
        $("#login_errors").html(info)
      };
    });

  // Prevent the default action from occurring.
  return false;
});
```

Does anybody know how to fix this issue?

Comment: what does your `info` object look like - you look like you are trying to access a `status` property, yet you seem to set the variable as html wherever you are processing the form

Comment: i'm not really sure tbh, I am completely new to ajax and just followed a small tutorial. What is the info object supposed to look like? I don;t even know what the info object is?

Comment: use console.log(info) to check what you are getting.

Comment: it says -  Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience.

Comment: what does that mean?

Answer (score 3):

Going wrong with this line `header('Location: home.php');`, this is a PHP statement which you are trying to use under JS.

you could use, `window.location = "home.php";` to redirect under JS.

**Another thing what i believe is faulty**

the callback function expects two parameters,

1. the content what you return on your action script.
2. the status of posted form

change `function(info) {`  to `function(info, status) {`

and use under you if statement, something like this `if (status!="success") {`

know more about `post in JS` : http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_get_post.asp

Comment: I tried that already and it still doesn't work, thats why i tried the php header location to see if that maybe works.

Comment: Do you know of any other reason this may be happening and how to fix it?

Comment: actually thats an wrong idea, when you say, i tried Js redirect, when it didn't work, you shifted to php.

Comment: I know, but how do I fix the current propblem of loading onto the same div rather than loading a new page?

Comment: because window.location = "home.php"; still does the same thing

Comment: http://code.runnable.com/UyClLhrKWGFrcrQW/simple-php-mysql-jquery-login-script check this wonderful ajaxLogin plugin, you will get an idea, where to correct it..